# A weakening of infinite Golomb rulers for group actions

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-actions

If a group $G$ acts on a space $X$, then a Golomb ruler is a subset $A$ of $X$ such that $|gA\cap A|\le 1$ for all $g\in G\backslash\{e\}$.

I am interested in a weaker concept, let's call it a "Golombish ruler", where for any $g\in G$ either $g$ has all but finitely many members of $A$ as fixed points or $|gA\cap A|<\infty$. (I.e., $gA\cap A$ is almost empty unless $g$ is almost identity on $A$.)

**Question:** Under what circumstances does a group action admit an infinite Golombish ruler?

If $G=X$ and $G$ is infinite, then there is an infinite Golomb ruler. Similarly, if only the identity element in $G$ has a fixed point and $G$ is infinite, there is an infinite Golomb ruler.

If $|G|>1$, $|X|=\infty$ and every nonidentity element of $G$ fixes all but finitely many members of $X$, there is an infinite Golombish ruler (any infinite set will do) but no infinite Golomb ruler.

I haven't found a case with infinite $X$ where there is no infinite Golombish ruler.

I am particularly interested in the case where $G$ (or at least $G$'s action on $X$) is supramenable, but I don't know if adding supramenability or amenability into the mix helps with anything.

Comment: Let $T$ be the set of vertices of a regular binary rooted tree (one can see $T$ as the set $\{0,1\}$-words, and the predecessor of any word of length $n\ge 1$ is its $(n-1)$-prefix. Let $G$ be the automorphism group of $T$. Let $W$ be the set of subsets of $T$ consisting of all finite prefixes of one given infinite $\{0,1\}$-word. Then $G$ acts transitively on $W$ and each $R\in W$ is an "infinite Golombish ruler" in your terminology, for the $G$-action on $T$ (note that $G$ and $W$ are uncountable while $T$ is countable).

Comment: Where does the (strange to me) terminology "Golomb ruler" arise from? The web search I did on "Golomb ruler" points to another notion ("set of marks at integer positions along a ruler such that no two pairs of marks are the same distance apart").

Comment: In the integers, Golomb rulers coincide with (a special case of) Sidon sets, but the generalisation to an arbitrary group is straighforward. Often Golomb rulers crop up in discussions about sequences with small autocorrelation (for applications in communications). If I remember rightly Golomb was motivated by optimal placements of receivers for a signal from a satellite.

Comment: @YCor: Let $G=\mathbb Z$ acting on itself. Then the two notions coincide. There is some work on Golomb rulers in the case of abelian groups acting on themselves, and I think yesterday I saw someone giving the (easy) proof of the existence of a Golomb ruler for the general case of an infinite group acting on itself. I am not sure I've seen the term "Golomb ruler" for an arbitrary group action. My interest is connected to contructing $G$-invariant means on subsets of $X$ that needn't be $G$-invariant, and Golomb rulers are intuitively pretty much as far from $G$-invariant as can be.